# Getting the last modify date of a directory in ftp

Tags: c#-4.0

How do i get when a directory was recently modify via  ftp using c#

I have tried this, with no luck

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpAddress + "/" + "public_html" + "/" + this.Url)); 
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUsername, FTPPassword); 
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp; 
DateTime FtpFileLastModified = ((FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse()).LastModified; 
return FtpFileLastModified;
```

Comment: FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpAddress + "/" + "public_html" + "/" + this.Url));
                     ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUsername, FTPPassword);
                     ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
                     DateTime FtpFileLastModified = ((FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse()).LastModified;
                     return FtpFileLastModified;

Comment: Right. Does it throw an error? Empty response? Fire is set and people is dying? :)

Comment: File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access). error